# Adding Role To Discord Member on Join

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.io

I'm trying to code a Discord bot using js that will welcome new joiners to the server and assign them "Trial member" role for 7 days. I have been unable to get the auto assigning of roles to work. I will include my code below and any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks.

```
/////Generic Authorization and packages////
var Discord = require('discord.io');
var logger = require('winston');
var auth = require('./auth.json');

// Configure logger settings
logger.remove(logger.transports.Console);
logger.add(new logger.transports.Console, {
    colorize: true
});
logger.level = 'debug';
// Initialize Discord Bot 
const bot = new Discord.Client({
  token: auth.token,
  autorun: true
});
bot.on('ready', function (evt) {
    logger.info('Connected');
    logger.info('Logged in as: ');
    logger.info(bot.username + ' - (' + bot.id + ')');


});
```

//////Code Block with issue Starts Here \\\

```
bot.on('guildMemberAdd', member => {
  
    console.log('User ' + member.username + ' has joined the server!')
    var roleid = '746791647140118591';
    member.roles.add('746791647140118591').then(()=> {
      bot.sendMessage({
        to: member.id,
        message: 'beep boop!'
      })
    });
```

////// End of Problem Code Block

```
//protocol for setting the start date of the trial membership
    var currentDate = new Date();
    var day = currentDate.getDate();
    var month = currentDate.getMonth() + 1;
    var year = currentDate.getFullYear();
    var date_formatted = month + '/' + day + '/' + year; 
// protocol for setting the end date of the trial membership
    var end_date = new Date();
    end_date.setDate(end_date.getDate()+7);
    var end_day = end_date.getDate();
    var end_month = end_date.getMonth()+ 1;
    var end_year =  end_date.getFullYear();
    var formatted_end_date = end_month + '/' + end_day + '/' + end_year; 
    
    console.dir(member);
    userID=member.id;
    bot.sendMessage({
        to: member.id,

        message: 'Hi there ' +member.username+ '! Welcome to Stonks Society- we\'re glad you\'re here. Your trial membership begins today ('+ date_formatted +') and will expire in seven days ('+ formatted_end_date +')'

    })

 //    });

});
```

Comment: What version of `discord.js` are you using?

Comment: Can you describe the issue you are having in more detail and highlight the parts of code with the problem, or post a minimal code to show the problem?

Comment: @Lioness100 I am using the most recent version of discord.js (12.3.1)

Comment: @Sebi I have created a separation in the code, hopefully making the problem code more clear. I get the following error "member.roles.add('746791647140118591').then(()=> {
                 ^

TypeError: member.roles.add is not a function"

Comment: something is bothering me. Why are you importing `discord.io`? Are you using discord.js or discord.io?

Comment: @JackRed I am using discord.js- This was a mistake as I was troubleshooting and forgot to change this back. sorry about the confusion. the error still appears even with the correction.

Comment: I am not sure about the answer you accepted then. If you are using discord.js, why accepting an answer giving solution for discord.io?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using discord.io not discord.js, to add a role using discord.io you should do

```js
var roleID = '746791647140118591';
var serverID = 'the ID of the server';

bot.addToRole({
  serverID: serverID,
  roleID: roleID,
  userID: member.id
}, (err) => {
  if(err) console.log(err);
});
```

For more information you can read the documentation [here](https://izy521.gitbooks.io/discord-io/content/Methods/Users.html)